Fast sampling from Fermi-Dirac distribution under specific conditions
This question is a continuation of the following one.
Let us assume a Fermi-Dirac (FD) distribution (times $p^{2}$):
AvalFD = Integrate[x^2/(Exp[x/T] + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> T > 0];
DistrFD[T_,x_]=1/AvalFD*x^2/(Exp[x/T]+1);

I need to make a fast point sampler from it. There are a few complications:

I need to sample a very small number of points (in practice, 1 or 2) but many times (so there should be no lower time threshold for calling the sampler).
The temperature is a dynamic parameter - it changes from time to time (so it may be complicated to precompute the inverse CDF).
I need to sample inside a compiled code (so the sampling code must be compilable).

This is my approach:
FastFDsampler = 
  Compile[{{npoints, _Integer}, {T, _Real}}, 
   Module[{pts, weights},
    pts = RandomReal[{0, 10 T}, 50 npoints];
    weights = pts^2/(Exp[pts/T] + 1);
    RandomSample[weights -> pts, npoints]
    ]
   , CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
FastFDsampler[1, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
sss = FastFDsampler[10000, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
Show[Histogram[sss, 30, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
 Plot[DistrFD[3, x], {x, 0, 30}]]


{0.0000379,Null}
{0.0112687,Null}


It first samples points uniformly within some range, then computes the weights from the distribution DistrFD, and then resamples. The method is not very good, as one must first generate a much larger amount of points than the desired number of final points (the difference between the uniform distribution and FD is huge); also, there is an upper limit on the maximal value of the generated value (10T in the example) imposed by hand.
As an alternative, I came up with the following approach:
FastFDsampler2 = 
 Compile[{{npoints, _Integer}, {T, _Real}}, 
  Module[{ptsBoltzmann, weightsRatio},
   (*Sampling points according to the Boltzmann distribution \
E^2Exp[-E/T] - to account for the correct high-energy tail*)
   ptsBoltzmann = -T*Total[Log[#]] & /@ 
     RandomVariate[
      UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], {5 npoints, 3}];
   (*Ratio of the weigths - Fermi-Dirac over Boltzmann*)
   weightsRatio = Exp[ptsBoltzmann/T]/(Exp[ptsBoltzmann/T] + 1);
   (*Resampling the points*)
   RandomSample[weightsRatio -> ptsBoltzmann, npoints]
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
FastFDsampler2[1, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
sss2 = FastFDsampler2[10000, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
Show[Histogram[{sss2, -3*Total[Log[#]] & /@ 
    RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], {10^4, 2 + 1}]}, 100, 
  "ProbabilityDensity"], Plot[DistrFD[3, x], {x, 0, 30}]]
Show[Histogram[{sss, sss2}, 100, "ProbabilityDensity"], 
 Plot[DistrFD[3, x], {x, 0, 30}]]


{0.0000323,Null}
{0.0107477,Null}


It first samples points according to the Boltzmann distribution, then computes the weights as the ratio of the values of FD and Boltzmann distributions, and then resamples. I assume that it would require a much smaller number of points - simply because the Boltzmann and FD distributions differ only in the domain of small x.
Is there any faster/more reliable approach for the specified conditions?

Is there a known range of values of $T$?

@JimB you can assume $T=1$ and then scale the results at the end. No need to worry about the value of $T$!

@Roman.  Good!  That means HenrickShumacher 's inverse sample suggestion will work fine for the previous question at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/301633/how-to-quickly-sample-from-the-following-distributions.

@JimB : would it be really an option given that I woild need to use interpolations? The built-in interpolation is very slow, and a custom one would still require some way of handling.

I'm not understanding your question.  First, I know nothing about using Compile. Is having a "piecewise-linear approximant" an impossibility when using Compile?

Perhaps its a good idea to use the InverseFunction of the CDF.
Make the functions parameter dependent an real numeric
    AvalFD[T_,x_]=Integrate[x^2/(Exp[x/T]+1),{x,0,Infinity},
       Assumptions->T>0]//N;
     DistrFD[T_,x_]:=1/AvalFD[T,x]*x^2/(Exp[x/T]+1);

Integrate the distribution, as for as it goes
     ICDFa[p_] := 
    Evaluate[
   InverseFunction[( 
     Function @@ {x, 
         Integrate[DistrFD[1, xi], {xi, 0, x}, 
               Assumptions :> x > 0]})] 
           [p]]

      ICDFa[y] // FullForm

$$\text{InverseFunction}\left[x \mapsto 1.10921 x \text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-x}\right)+1.10921 \text{Li}_3\left(-e^{-x}\right)-0.554605 x^2 \log \left(e^{-x}+1\right)+1.\right][y]$$
Making the function Listable makes it possible to use samples from uniform distribution in $(0,1)$ as argument
  SetAttributes[ICDFa, {NumericFunction, Listable}]


  Timing[sample = ICDFa[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000]];]
  {1.25, Null}

 ListPlot[{sample, Sort[sample]}]


